# Open Google Map search box in modal

Tags: angular

How to open google maps search box in modal box after entering address to find the google url for particular address in angular 6

Answer (score 0):

> You can take advantage of **JavaScript** API which targets Google Maps
>   features.

Since *Angular's TypeScript* code will be compiled eventually in *JavaScript* code before being sent to the browser, you can write pure JavaScript with no worries ( you are very likely to find a useful API on this topic in JavaScript world).

Here is a very good video tutorial which will guide you step by step to maps enhancement using this Google Maps JS API: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zxf1mnP5zcw

Also, further useful information could be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: Thanks for solution, and it is ok but i want to open that map finder in modal box and i want  google url of that particular address, if anyone have any solution then let me know....please